# Current iteration number in Python for loop

Tags: python

I am sure there is a better way or writing this python function:

```
end_points = list(range(100))
filepath = 'something.csv'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    cnt = 0
    for line in fp:
        end_points[cnt]=[x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
        cnt += 1
```

It works but it is not elegant. Is there a way of automatically refers to the current number of iteration in the `for loop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the enumerate function:

```
for iteration_no, line in enumerate(fp):
    print(iteration_no)
    end_points[iteration_no]=[x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
```

If you are more generally interested in seeing the progress of your loop you should alternatively have a look at the TQDM package which dynamically prints the progress of your loop.

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of being elegant but is shorter,

```py
>>> with open("something.csv") as f:
...     result = [list(map(str.strip,x.split(','))) for x in f]
...     print(result)
```